# how do i get my python program to exit and show an error message if an invalid input is entered?

Tags: python, input, message, exit, equation

This is the code I have so far..

```
#solving a quadratic equation
#finding conjugate pair of imaginary roots if no real roots

import math
import sys

a = float(input('Enter a: '))
b = float(input('Enter b: '))
c = float(input('Enter c: '))

try:
    # find the discriminant
    d = (b**2)-(4*a*c) 

    if d < 0:
        import cmath #importing complex math to find imaginay roots
        x1 = (-b-cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
        x2 = (-b+cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)

        print"This equation gives a conjugate pair of imaginary roots: ", x1, " and", x2

    elif d == 0:
        x = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
        print "This equation has one solutions: ", x

    else:
        x1 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
        x2 = (-b-math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
        print "This equation has two solutions: ", x1, " and", x2

except:
    SystemExit
```

I need to make my program robust against the user entering non-numerical data. I have tried using conditional ststements (if..elif..else) and tried exception handling.

I need the program to show an error message and prompt the user to try again

HELP

Comment: `float` with throw an `ValueError` if the input couldn't be converted to float. Use a `while(True):` loop and a `try except` if no exception   is thrown do a break and move on.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**

You probably want to turn

```
a = float(input('Enter a: '))
b = float(input('Enter b: '))
c = float(input('Enter c: '))
```

to

```
def get_input(s):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input('Enter %s: ' % s))
        except ValueError:
            print 'Error: Invalid Input.'


a = get_input('a')
b = get_input('b')
c = get_input('c')
```

Comment: wrap that in a `while(True)` and remove `exit()` and add a `break` if no exception is thrown and you have answered to question from OP :-)